# Four Column Layout that Converts to Single Column without Media Query

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I'm trying to create a four column layout where each column grows and shrinks with the size of the window, but each column has a minimum width and when the window is too small for all four columns to fit in a single row, it transitions to a single column with each section taking up the full width.

I've been unable to do this with either flex-box or CSS grid. And I'd like to do this without a media query.  Using a media query would solve the issue pretty easily, but I don't like them!

```css
.col {
  width: 100%; 
  display: flex; 
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.section {
  margin: 10px 0px 0px 10px;
  min-width: 250px; 
  height: 400px; 
  background-color: gray;
  flex: auto; 
}
```

```html
<div class="col">
  <div class="section">
  </div>
   <div class="section">
  </div>
   <div class="section">
  </div>
   <div class="section">
  </div>
</div>
```

And a codepen: https://codepen.io/WriterState/pen/oRKxMj

Comment: You don’t like them? Or you don’t know how to use them properly? A media query is the simple, effective, and proper way to solve this problem.

Comment: I don't like them, but use them all of the time. 

It just feels like there should be a built-in solution to this, either with flex or grid.

Comment: Well feel free to run a google search. Here is a starting point: https://css-tricks.com/look-ma-no-media-queries-responsive-layouts-using-css-grid/ . Make sure you consider browser support. I maintain that media queries are currently the way to go.

Comment: moving from 4 columns to 1 column would not be possible, but from 4 to 3 and then 2 and 1 column may be possible without media query :)

Comment: Media queries are based on the width of the window and not the width of the container. If the container is within a fluid layout media queries would not work.

Answer (score 0):

Media queries are great, but they are not always a viable substitute for [container queries](https://alistapart.com/article/container-queries-once-more-unto-the-breach/) (which sadly do not exist).

A horizontal to vertical layout switch can be achieved using CSS `calc` when you know how many columns you will have.

```
.child{
   min-width: 25%; /* 100% divide number columns */
   max-width: 100%;
   width: calc((50rem - 100%) * 1000); /* Replace 50rem with size of .parent when you want switch to happen */
}
```

The width is calculated as your desired breakpoint minus the width of the parent container. This either generates a negative number and the `min-width` is applied, or a large number in which case the `max-width` takes over.

If you are using flex-box then `width` can also be `flex-basis`.

Source: https://www.sitepoint.com/responsive-css-patterns-without-media-queries/

Comment: You can actually streamline this down even cleaner and without burning your max-width and min-width: 
`width: clamp(25%, calc((50rem - 100%) * 1000), 100%);` accomplishes the exact same thing for the exact same reasons, but only occupies a single property (which itself is handy if there's conditions in which you need to either animate or throttle back the calculated value, too). Since it's a pain to animate indeterminate widths, you can use this extended calculation and still leave your max-width for your keyframes, or pseudo-selector triggers, as a for-instance.