# CSS Grid - Transitioning from 1 row, 3 col to 3 row, 1 col

Tags: css, css-grid, grid-layout

I'm exploring CSS Grid to see if it can completely replace the need for responsive CSS media queries for my specific use case. I have the following grid container:

```css
.gridContainer {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(250px, 1fr));
    padding: 0px 15px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    grid-row-gap: 20px;
}
```

The grid container holds three items that initially result in one row and three columns on larger screen sizes:

[image]

When I reduce the viewport width such that the three columns are below 250px each, I would like the grid layout to snap to a layout of three rows and one column:

[image]

As you reduce the viewport width, there is currently an interim layout where the third item wraps onto a row where it sits by itself, due to the auto-placement algorithm selected:

[image]

I would like to bypass this wrapping and only support the initial one-row, three-column layout and the final three-row, one-column layout. Is this possible with CSS Grid only and without the use of media queries?

Comment: I have written an answer to this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56621930/four-column-layout-that-converts-to-single-column-without-media-query/64326612#64326612

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a mediaquerie and turn your container into a grid once a minimal width is reach : *(code option taken since you gave so little infos)*

basis example of the idea

```css
div {
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 1em;
  border: dotted tomato;
}

@media (min-width: 780px) {
  body {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(250px, 1fr));
    padding: 0px 15px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    grid-row-gap: 20px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>lorem</div>
<div>lorem</div>
<div>lorem</div>
```

You can play the snippet in full page mode  and resize your browser to check out the behavior.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is actually what I currently have implemented, but I was more so wondering if I could achieve this same functionality without the use of media queries. I edited the end of my post to be more clear.

Comment: you can't really , below 250px your grid cell won't shrink but also won't expand unless content does  (an image, a very long word,  something with a width set to more than 250px, ..) mediaquerie is the only thing here that can watch the size of the window and switch to other css rules of yours.

Answer (score 1):

The auto-fit or auto-fill functions fills the available space with the maximum number of columns.

You can solve the problem with the help of media expressions, changing the number of columns at the required resolution.

### Result

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, minmax(250px, 1fr));
  padding: 0px 15px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  grid-row-gap: 20px;
  list-style: none;
}

.item {
  border: 1px dashed red;
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
  .grid {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul class="grid">
  <li class="item">
    <h3>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Iusto nihil neque quas corrupti eaque in iure totam reiciendis praesentium. Sapiente impedit magni consequatur modi error eaque vel tempore consequuntur saepe.</p>
  </li>
  <li class="item">
    <h3>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Iusto nihil neque quas corrupti eaque in iure totam reiciendis praesentium. Sapiente impedit magni consequatur modi error eaque vel tempore consequuntur saepe.</p>
  </li>
  <li class="item">
    <h3>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Iusto nihil neque quas corrupti eaque in iure totam reiciendis praesentium. Sapiente impedit magni consequatur modi error eaque vel tempore consequuntur saepe.</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

And same code on [CodePen](https://codepen.io/hisbvdis/pen/BaBMLWP)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is actually what I currently have implemented, but I was more so wondering if I could achieve this same functionality without the use of media queries. I edited the end of my post to be more clear.